# Unexpected overflow padding in eclipse php editor

Tags: eclipse

After fresh install Eclipse Oxygen 3a on Ubuntu 16.04, my php editor come with large padding that overflow and hide text content.
Here is a screenshoot of what IDE look like:
[image: big border]
You can see a big black border overflow code

That padding will disappear if scroll to the edge:
[image]

That border appear inside any window that has scroll bar like project explorer and prefences

Comment: Is this the normal _Dark_ theme? Do you have the same problem with the default light theme?

Comment: @howlger Yes, i used normal Dark theme, and i got same problem with Light theme, I still can see cursor pointer blinking while navigate behind that border but not the text

Comment: If you still have the problem with the [preview version of Eclipse Photon](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php), please [report it to Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform).